# Converting Vector to HashSet in Java

Tags: java, collections

Could someone explain, how the following code printed the Vector elements (in which order they were printed)?

### Code:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Vector;
class Test
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        Vector data = new Vector();
        data.add("apple");
        data.add("mango");
        data.add("papaya");
        data.add("cherry");
        data.add("banana");
        data.add("apple");
        System.out.println(getData(data));
    }
    public static Vector getData(Vector v)
    {
        return new Vector(new HashSet(v));
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
[banana, cherry, papaya, apple, mango]
```

Comment: There is no ordering in a `HashSet`

Comment: But, everytime how I am getting the same output(in same order)?

Comment: Hashset doesn;t have any restriction to push elemets in a particular order but it might be using a common algo to pull information out. So you may get it in same order everytime.

Comment: Any given set of elements will *probably* end up in the same order given the same sequence of operations. There is no predictable *ordering*.

Comment: I want to know, how "banana" got printed first, & then "cherry", "papaya" ..etc..? Why elements are printed in reverse order until "papaya"? As there is 'no predictable ordering' maintained, then assuming we should get different o/p at different times. But its not, so pls explain, how it is working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Hashset doesn't store elements in a user specified Order. As soon as you created the Hashset using Vector, Elements lost the specified order.
2. Moreover they don't allow duplicates, so the second apple got lost.

Comment: If elements lost the specified order, why I am getting the following same o/p (in same order), every time I ran? _O/P_: **[banana, cherry, papaya, apple, mango]**. It should be printed in different order, when ran in different machines. But same o/p is getting shown. Also, can we tell the output for the above program, w/o running, i.e., manually (as there is no specific order for o/p)?